# laravel-translatable does not work with vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am building a project using Laravel + Vue, I used Vuei18n to localization in vue ,and laravel-translatable was used in Laravel ,but laravel-translatable does not work in a components, it shows all translations of the data, for example:

```
{en: "Hello" , ar:"مرحبا"}
```

on laravel I was using Middleware and Prefix to display the text depending on the language, but with vue + laravel this feature does not work.

is there any suggestion or solutions?

Comment: Check if this help? https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable/issues/193

Comment: @shahidiqbal i can't find the answer can you help me please